# Conditional Random Fields and the Label Bias Problem

Tags: nlp, tagging

I was reading [this paper](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~pereira/papers/crf.pdf) about conditional random fields and was confused by the "label bias problem" mentioned in the paper.  I've looked online for some explanations of it but still don't feel like I have a good grasp of the issue. What exactly is the label bias problem? Can someone provide a clear example of it and why it is bad?

Comment: While I can understand why this might have been closed, I don't believe closing this question was a good decision. Conditional Random Fields are closely related to software development in the fields of machine learning and natural language processing (in fact, adapting a conditional random field to do POS tagging is what I'm working on).  Additionally, I've seen many other questions concerning conditional random fields that seem to deal with programming just as much as my question does (I could point to them if necessary).

Comment: The closing makes sense I think, since this wasn't asked as a programming question -- it was asked more as a question of theory. Perhaps http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask?